# Can I get more specifics on changing the Continue Shopping URL in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, url, shopping-cart

I have seen the following answer to my specific question, but as a NEWBIE, I need a little more information

Someone said 
...
create your own helper that has a method getContinueUrl that returns the desired url and modify the markup above to

```
<action method="setContinueShoppingUrl"><url helper="helper_alias/getContinueUrl" /></action>
```

Or you can create an observer that set's the url on the block:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.cart')->setContinueShoppingUrl('URL HERE');
```

The second option is to create an observer that sets the url in session. This can be used if you want a dynamic continue url. Add this in your observer.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setContinueShoppingUrl('URL HERE')
```

...

Most of that doesn't make enough sense to me so I need a little more direction please.  I tried changing my checkout/cart.phtml file to show the hard url but nothing is changing.  Can someone please tell me exactly which file path to use to find exactly the right file and what bits I need to change and what I need to change them to?

Many thanks

Comment: If you want to use the method suggested with your own helper you will need to create your own module - if you are not sure how to do that then it's really a bit too much of a broad question for here.  How much do you understand about creating your own module?

Comment: I will spend some time today reading up about creating modules and then see if that helps any.  Will come back to you once I have done that.